# ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool Not Finding Any Databases

Tags: sql, roleprovider, sqlmembershipprovider

I am trying to use the ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool to setup my database for Membership Roles and ASP.NET Users however it cannot find any database when I clearly have one. I am using SQL Express, does that play any role?

Comment: Can you post your aspnet_regsql command line parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using for the `-S` (server) parameter?  You must use `ServerName\InstanceName`.  By default, SQL Server Express has an instance name of `SQLEXPRESS`.  Therefore, most like you should be using `YourServerName\SQLEXPRESS`.